# Can I alter the mysql query depends on user entry, php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a situation is that the query depends on user entry. If user enter toy, then query will have some OR, if user enter TV, then the query will slightly different. The simple way to do that is like below. However, when I have a lot of different products, what is the best way to do it? I want to create an array to include all products and use if condition inside the query, but if this doable or any better way? appreciate.

```html
<?php
if ($toy){
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT DISTINCT product FROM dis WHERE cat IN (%s, %s, %s)  
AND (val !=%s AND mark='price') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='country') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='shipping') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='quality') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='frequency') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='duration')
 ",$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f));
}
if($tv){
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
  SELECT DISTINCT product FROM dis WHERE cat IN (%s, %s, %s)  
AND (val !=%s AND mark='price') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='country') 
or (val !=%s AND mark='shipping') 
 ",$a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f));
}
/*I have a lot*/
?>
```

Comment: Please add two other examples to your question (besides `$toy` and `$tv`) so we can be confident that we understand the correct query pattern.  Also are you sure the queries above are correct?  Because in both cases you have 6 arguments `$a` through `$f` but the first query has a lot more `%s` placeholders than the second query.

Comment: One ought to google on "dynamic PHP query builder implode"

Answer (score 0):

You can either store the mapping (between product types and their parameters) inside PHP code or inside a database table. In the case you store it in PHP:

```
$mapping = Array(
  'toy' => Array('country', 'shipping', 'quality', 'frequency', 'duration'),
  'tv'  => Array('country', 'shipping')
);

$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT product FROM dis WHERE cat IN (';
foreach($category as $k=>$v) $category[$k] = '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($v).'"';
$query .= implode(',', $category);
$query .= ') AND ((val !="'.mysql_real_escape_string($price).'" AND mark="price") ';
foreach($mapping[$kind] as $v) 
  $query .= ' or (val !="'.mysql_real_escape_string($parameter[$v]).'" AND mark="'.$v.'")';
$query .= ')';
$sql = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Looking at your SQL I can presume that you have one big table for all products - and each product is represented with many rows, one row for each of the parameters of the product. This is a **BAD design** !
You'd better use 2 separate tables - one will contain only the products (only 1 row for each product) and the other table will contain product parameters (using ONE-to-MANY relationship) - each parameter on a distinct row.

Comment: If I design two table, then second table also have a lot of rows. Then why should I separate them? Two tables is slower?

Comment: You have to separate them because you put different kind of products in the first table. If you were putting only 1 kind of product - then 1 table is the right choice. But since obviously you can not create new table for every new KIND of products you want to store - you place all those attributes that are common among all product KINDS in table PRODUCT and place all specific attributes in table PARAMETER. In this case you will not need to use DISTINCT in your query, and will not need to update the name of a given product at dozen different rows.